# Python - Copy link of currently used page

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium on Python. With this short example below, I switch from the page [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) to another page, finding in the search bar the sentence: "some text".

Now, I need to copy the new url generated:
[image]

Is it possible to copy this link (*google.com/search?q...*) with Python, by assigning a variable name to the link?

Below, the code used to arrive to this page

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


link = 'https://www.google.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()
print(driver.page_source)


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Accept']").click() # Accept Cookies
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[class="gLFyf gsfi"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[class="gLFyf gsfi"]').send_keys('some text')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[class="gLFyf gsfi"]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current URL is available as `driver.current_url` so just add

```
url = driver.current_url
print(url)
```

immediately after last line